# using System.IO.Ports в c# dll

Tags: c#

Как мне использовать SerialPort в проекте библиотека классов c#. В обычном консольном проекте  просто подключаю using System.IO.Ports но в проекте dll мне выдает
Ошибка  CS0234  Тип или имя пространства имен "Ports" не существует в пространстве имен "System.IO" (возможно, отсутствует ссылка на сборку).

Comment: Проверьте, какой установлен "Target Framework"  в свойствах проекта.

Comment: .NET Standart 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пространство имён System.IO.Ports [недоступно](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports?view=netframework-4.7.2&viewFallbackFrom=netstandard-2.0) в .NET Standard.

Есть два способа решения этой проблемы.

1. Перейти на .NET Core - здесь эта библиотека [доступна](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports?view=netcore-2.0).
2. Использовать NuGet [пакет](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.Ports/).

Comment: И это всё равно не особо поможет. System.IO.Ports поддерживается только на Windows. Так что, если делать нужно кроссплатформенное решение, придётся использовать пакет SerialPortStream и не забыть собрать нативную библиотеку под линуксом